# Error Converting a time series with NA values to data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, time-series

I want to convert a time series into a data frame and keep the same format. The problem is this ts has some NA values that come from a previous calculation step and I can't fill them by interpolation. I tried to remove the NA's from the time series before converting it but I get an error that I don't even understand what it is.

My time series is the following; it has only two NAs at the beginning (an excerpt)

```
>spi_ts_3
              Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun
1989           NA           NA  0.765069346  1.565910141  1.461138946  1.372936681
1990 -0.157878028  0.097403112  0.099963471  0.729772909  0.569480219 -0.419761595
1991 -0.157878028  0.348524568  0.230534719  0.356331349  0.250889358  0.353116608
1992  1.662879078  2.178001602  1.379790538  1.367209519  1.367845061  1.451183431
1993  0.096554376  0.058881807  0.247172184 -0.085316621  0.020991171 -0.491276965
1994  0.258656104  0.716903968  0.847780489  0.440594371  0.474698780 -0.473765100
```

The code I'm using to convert it and handle the NAs is the following>

```
library(tseries)
na.remove(spi_ts_3)
df_fitted_3 <- as.data.frame(type.convert(.preformat.ts(spi_ts_3)))
```

When I check at the data frame produced, I don't even understand what is happening. I get something like this for each month and a warning at end of all months.

```
 type.convert(.preformat.ts(spi_ts_3)).Feb
1                                          NA
2                                 0.097403112
3                                 0.348524568
4                                 2.178001602
5                                 0.058881807
6                                 0.716903968
7                                 2.211192460
8                                -1.123925787
9                                 0.395452064
10                               -0.106514633
11                               -1.637049815
12                               -0.862751319
13                               -0.010681104
14                               -0.958173964
15                                0.470583289
16                                0.088061116
17                                0.485598080
18                               -0.661229419
19                                1.323879689
20                               -0.449031840
21                               -1.867196593
22                                0.598343928
23                               -2.549778490
24                               -0.174824280
25                                0.892977124
26                               -0.246675932
27                                0.324195405
28                               -0.296931389
29                                0.356029416
30                                0.171029515
31                                       <NA>
32                                       <NA>
33                                       <NA>
34                                       <NA>
35                                       <NA>
36                                       <NA>
37                                       <NA>
38                                       <NA>
39                                       <NA>
40                                       <NA>
41                                       <NA>
42                                       <NA>
43                                       <NA>
44                                       <NA>
45                                       <NA>
46                                       <NA>
47                                       <NA>
48                                       <NA>
49                                       <NA>
50                                       <NA>
51                                       <NA>
52                                       <NA>
53                                       <NA>
54                                       <NA>
55                                       <NA>
56                                       <NA>
57                                       <NA>
58                                       <NA>
59                                       <NA>
60                                       <NA>
61                                       <NA>
62                                       <NA>
63                                       <NA>
64                                       <NA>
65                                       <NA>
66                                       <NA>
67                                       <NA>
68                                       <NA>
69                                       <NA>
70                                       <NA>
71                                       <NA>
72                                       <NA>
73                                       <NA>
74                                       <NA>
75                                       <NA>
76                                       <NA>
77                                       <NA>
78                                       <NA>
79                                       <NA>
80                                       <NA>
81                                       <NA>
82                                       <NA>
83                                       <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Comment: 1) why not fill them and remove them later? if you really have just 2 NA's this seems a dirty but quick fix. 2) why remove the NA first? 3) please use data derived from `dput()` so we can replicate the data.

Comment: The thing is that there are 2 in this case but there is a worse case where there are 11

Comment: of course, it would not be a generalized solution which makes it, in most cases, pointless. still, i didn't manage to reproduce your problem with some mock-data i wrote myself. it works fine with NA. so i am not sure what causes the problem

Comment: my problem is that with the code I am using for some reason the dataframe has 1 variable and 360 observations

Comment: well, if you can't give a better example, you can always copy your data as is into an excel sheet, put in the correct separators via Text-to-columns (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) and then  save it as csv. easy to read in as dataframe with any read.table command

Comment: I fixed it! all O had to do was create a new ts like this                                      
                                                                                                                        
`spi_ts_6 <- na.remove(spi_6_gamma$fitted)`
`df_fitted_6 <- as.data.frame(type.convert(.preformat.ts(spi_ts_6)))`

Comment: congratulations :)